# WP Rockets 'WP Rocket | Exclude JS scripts from Delay JS only at some URLs' helper plugin not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

can anyone help me. I am using this helper plugin to exclude scripts from "Delay Javascript Execution", https://github.com/wp-media/wp-rocket-helpers/tree/master/static-files/wp-rocket-static-exclude-delay-js-per-url/.

The pages are home page and tablets page, slick.min.js and jquery.min.js are the scripts that I would like to exclude on these pages. In my knowledge, I have done everything correctly, I have added tablets in the '$excluded_slugs' array and I have added '(is_front_page())' in the if condition.

I even tried adding '(is_page_template('home-v4.php'))' and '(is_page_template('tablet.php'))' in the if condition, cause this pages are custom page template but its still not working. You can see these on below links, as you can observe the carousel images stack on each other on page load(this can be better observe in mobile), this is because the jquery.min.js and slick.min.js is not been loaded, it needs user interaction before it loads.

Below is my 'wp-rocket-exclude-delay-js-per-url.php' file.

```
/**
 * Plugin Name: WP Rocket | Exclude JS scripts from Delay JS only at some URLs
 * Plugin URI: https://github.com/wp-media/wp-rocket-helpers/tree/master/static-files/wp-rocket-static-exclude-delay-js-per-url/
 * Description: Exclude JavaScript files from Delay JS only on specific pages instead of excluding them globally.
 * Version: 1.0
 * Author: WP Rocket Support Team
 * Author URI: https://wp-rocket.me
 * License: GNU General Public License v2 or later
 * License URI: http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html
 *
 * Copyright 2021 WP Media <support@wp-rocket.me>
 */
 

 // Namespaces must be declared before any other declaration.
 namespace WP_Rocket\Helpers\static_files\exclude\selective_delay_js_exclusions;
 
// Exit if accessed directly
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) exit; 
 
function exclude_from_delay( $exclusions ) {

        /**
        This helper will allow you exclude JavaScript files from Delay JS only on specific pages instead of excluding them globally.
        This plugin requires a 2 steps editing.
            
        STEP #1: ON THESE PAGES...
        Change the Slugs ("first-slug", etc, in this example) to the pages where you want to apply these exclusions.
        These are the URLs where the scripts from step 2 won't be delayed.
        For example: On the following pages (STEP #1), don't delay the following OWL Carousel scripts (STEP #2).
        **/
                
        $excluded_slugs = array( 
            'tablets', 
            //'another-slug', 
           // 'another-one', 
        );       
        // STOP EDITING
       
        if ( 
            
            ( function_exists( 'is_page' ) && is_page( $excluded_slugs ) ) 
            || ( function_exists( 'is_single' ) && is_single( $excluded_slugs ) )
            || (is_front_page())
            // || (is_page_template('home-v4.php')) 
            // || (is_page_template('tablet.php'))
           
           /* 
           IF YOU NEEED TO EXCLUDE BASED ON DIFFERENT RULES 
            you can replace lines 41 and 42 with different conditionals, or add more conditions, for example:
            || ( is_front_page() )
            || ( is_category() )
            ... etc
            */ 
           
        ) {
            
        /**
        STEP #2: DON'T DELAY THESE SCRIPTS!
        Add the scripts that need to be loaded right away ONLY on the above URLs. 
        To add multiple scripts you can duplicate these lines as meany times as needed.
        **/
        
        $exclusions[] = 'jquery.min.js';
        $exclusions[] = 'slick.min.js';
        //$exclusions[] = 'script2.js';
        //$exclusions[] = 'anotherInline';        
        // STOP EDITING
   
        }
    
    return $exclusions;

}

add_filter( 'rocket_delay_js_exclusions',  __NAMESPACE__ . '\exclude_from_delay' );
```

Any help would be greatly appriciated.

Comment: Try changing it to just `if(true)` for debugging purposes. This will test if the problem is with your exclusions themselves or something else.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the filter on a code snippets plugin, you need to set a high priority on the filter.

```
add_filter( 'rocket_delay_js_exclusions',  __NAMESPACE__ . '\exclude_from_delay', 999 );
```

If you are not using a code snippets plugin, reach out to support to have a look.